# Using Query String in a Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

Very simple question and yet I can't seem to find the right answer. How do I pass the value of a textbox into a query string in a sqldatasource? Below is the markup of the sqldatasource that I have so far.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsGPATLotFailures" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamRpt %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamRpt.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 
  s.insertionnumber
  , s.insertionreason
  , s.containername
  , s.wafernumber
  , s.OPCODE
  , s.trackinqty
  , s.totalgoodqty
  , s.totalrejectsqty
  , s.trackoutqty
  , ROUND(s.yield, 4) yield
  , ROUND(s.uppersyl, 4) uppersyl
  , ROUND(s.lowersyl, 4) lowersyl
  , s.gpatrejectsqty
  , ROUND(s.gpatyield, 4) gpatyield
  , s.trackouttime
FROM wsigssummary s
WHERE s.containername LIKE :lotID || '%'
ORDER BY s.trackouttime">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="lotID" 
                    QueryStringField="lotID" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Do I need to do code behind for it to work or anything? By the way, I am using ASP.Net, Oracle 11g and C# is my code behind. Thank you cool people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special type of parameter in `SqlDataSource` for values from controls - `ControlParameter`:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="lotID" 
        QueryStringField="lotID" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ParameterName" ControlID="TextBox1"
                          PropertyName="Text"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you for sharing. I didn't know that I can use both for just one datasource. But how do I make use of the Querystring? At least half of the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: @GianIsTheName, you want to use them for the same parameter?

Comment: Yes andrei. will that be possible?

Comment: Hi again @andrei. turns out that i cant use both selectparameters. so just used querystring. and now it is fine. i'd still mark this as answer though since this one lead me to the right one.